# Corona SDK: iPhone 5 adjustment

Tags: scripting, lua, coronasdk, iphone-5

I am using the following config.lua file when creating my mobile application.

The screen will not adjust to iPhone5 when building to device. It will, however, adjust when running on the simulator that corona provides.

Can you tell me if the problem lies in this file, or if it depends on some other implementation issue.

Thanks!

/S

```
local isTall = ( "iPhone" == system.getInfo( "model" ) ) and ( display.pixelHeight > 960 )

 -- iPad Configuration
 if ( string.sub( system.getInfo("model"), 1, 4 ) == "iPad" ) then
   application =
   {
      content =
      {
         width = 360,
         height = 480,
         scale = "letterBox",
         xAlign = "center",
         yAlign = "center",
         imageSuffix =
         {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
            ["@4x"] = 3.0,
         },
      },
   }

   -- iPhone5 Configuration
   elseif ( string.sub( system.getInfo("model"), 1, 2 ) == "iP" and display.pixelHeight > 960 ) then
   application =
   {
      content =
      {
         width = 320,
         height = 568,
         scale = "letterBox",
         xAlign = "center",
         yAlign = "center",
         imageSuffix =
         {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
            ["@4x"] = 3.0,
         },
      },
   }

   -- iPhone 3,4 and Older iPod Touch
   elseif ( string.sub( system.getInfo("model"), 1, 2 ) == "iP" ) then
   application =
   {
      content =
      {
         width = 320,
         height = 480,
         scale = "letterBox",
         xAlign = "center",
         yAlign = "center",
         imageSuffix =
         {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
            ["@4x"] = 3.0,
         },
      },
   } 

   -- Android, Kindle Fire, and Nook
   elseif ( display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth > 1.72 ) then
   application =
   {
      content =
      {
         width = 320,
         height = 570,
         scale = "letterBox",
         xAlign = "center",
         yAlign = "center",
         imageSuffix =
         {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
            ["@4x"] = 3.0,
         },
      },
   }

else
   application =
   {
      content =
      {
         width = 320,
         height = 512,
         scale = "letterBox",
         xAlign = "center",
         yAlign = "center",
         imageSuffix =
         {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
            ["@4x"] = 3.0,
         },
      },
   }

end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it!.

Apperently, and this is not clear at all in my opinion, one needs to add (To the application's root) a file called "Default-568h@2x.png" which tells the device to go iPhone5 mode!

This file should be a png with dimensions 640x1136

More info can be found at:

- http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/09/14/corona-guidelines-iphone-5-and-ios6-preliminary/

Under "Supporting tall apps"

Answer (score 0):

If you are building for landscape mode like

```
orientation = {
    default = "landscapeLeft",
    content = "landscapeLeft",
    supported = { "landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft"}
},
```

Use "Default-568h@2x.png" with dimensions 1136x640, otherwise you will have problems.